# Sample space of a probability experiment concerning $x$ identical balls and $y$ labeled boxes

Tags: probability

> Let's assume that we have $x$ identical balls and $y$ labeled boxes. We place each of the balls in a uniformly randomly chosen box independently of the other balls.
>
> What will be the sample space of this experiment $\Omega$?

The sample space will be every possible outcome given $x$ balls and $y$ boxes. I can find this for a specific value $x$ and $y$, but how do we generalize a function for all outcomes?

Comment: There are only a finite number of possible outcomes.  Since, you have an event for each x and y, what more do you want?

Comment: It is similar to distributing x identical objects among y groups. It should be $C(x+y-1,y-1)$

Comment: It should be emphasized that those outcomes in the sample space are *not equally likely to occur!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*".. we place each of the balls .."* can be interpreted in two different ways.

a) If (as it comes to be normally understood) you "throw" each ball sequentially
then it is assumed that for each ball you can make $y$ choices, each equi-probable,
and independent from the choices made for the preceeding balls.
Then you have $y^x$ different and equivalent ways of *throwing the balls*.

b) If instead you "pour" the undistinguishable balls simultaneously into the boxes,
and after that you are going to count the different occupancy profiles that you
you may get, each profile being equi-probable, that would be equivalent to
the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))
scheme, as well as to the [(weak) compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)
of $x$ into $y$ parts, which can be done in $\binom{x+y-1}{x}$ ways.